# How to generate expressions for a macro?

Tags: clojure, dsl

Since one cannot apply a macro to a list, e.g.

```clj
;; does not work
(apply -> [expr1 expr2 expr3])
```

How does one generate such expression:

```clj
(-> expr1
    expr2
    expr3)
```

Where

- `expr1` is generated by `(generate-expr1 f g h)`
- `expr2` is generated by `(generate-expr2 f g h)`
- `expr3` is generated by `(generate-expr3 f g h)`

---

**Context**

I'm trying to design an embedded DSL, e.g.

```clj
["increment" "increment" "increment"]
```

Which is then converted into code, e.g.

```clj
(fn [n] (-> n inc inc inc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate it with a macro e.g.

```
(defmacro opfun [op-names]
  (let [m {"increment" 'inc}
        ops (map m op-names)]
    `(fn [n#] (-> n# ~@ops))))
```

then

```
(opfun ["increment" "increment" "increment"])
```

if you need to provide your argument list at runtime you can interpret your structure directly e.g.

```
(defn build-eval [op-names]
  (let [m {"increment" inc}
        ops (map m op-names)]
    (fn [n] (reduce (fn [acc f] (f acc)) n ops))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm just getting acquainted with macros so this may be a stupid question: can you use macros at runtime though? These DSL data structure are supplied at runtime, so I need to generate _and_ evaluate code at the same time.

Comment: Many native Clojure features are actually macros built on top of more primitive features. Both these and user-defined macros are "used" at run-time.  For ultimate power, one could always use `eval`, although I cannot imagine that you would need that for a DSL.